# How can I render a template based on execution of a specific function- Javascript

Tags: javascript, templates

I have an underscore template and I want to render a specific code in the template based on the call of certain function.
Template:

```
<div id = "account-hover-container" style="display:none;">
    <div class = "form-horizontal" id="hover-group-container">

    <% _.each(obj,function(item){ %>
      <p class="accountName-overview">
          <label for="user-create-date" class="control-label col-xs-3" id="accountName-title">Name:</label>
          <label class="overlay-accountName"><%= item.accountname %></label>
         <hr id="main-overlay-hr"/>
     </p>
  <% });%>

         <div id="detail-container">
        <div class="form-group overlay-group">
            <label for="user-create-date" class="control-label col-xs-3"><%= messages.admin.account.createdAccount %></label>
            <label name="user-create-date" id="user-create-date" class="control-label col-xs-4"></label>
        </div>
 </div></div>
```

In the above template i want to execute the above for each loop only for a certain function(below). Rest I'd like to render on page load.

Js:

```
function popcheck(obj) {
   //obj is a json object having fields for names and emails.
   //do some stuff
}
```

Can I call popcheck funtion from the template and display those content inside for-each loop only for this function. Is this possible??
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two separate template, account-hover-container-template and accountname-overview-template.
Then you can render and insert accountname-overview-template inside popcheck function.

For example:

```
<div id = "account-hover-container" style="display:none;">
    ......
    <div class="accountname-overview-container"/>
    ......
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="accountname-overview-template">
    <% _.each(obj,function(item){ %>
    ......
    <% });%>
</scirpt>

function popcheck(obj) {
  var tmpl = _.template($(#accountname-overview-template).html());
  $('.accountname-overview-container').html(tmpl({obj: obj}));
}
```

Comment: that is wht i tried before and doing this, navigates me to a different page.I want to be in the same page and this div that im rendering would act like an overlay